# How to set up a callback in an initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Koudoku for subscriptions. I want to do different things after receiving a Stripe webhook.

[In the docs](https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku#webhooks), it shows you can add a callback like so:

```
Koudoku.setup do |config|
  config.subscriptions_owned_by = :user
  config.stripe_publishable_key = ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']
  config.stripe_secret_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']

  # add webhooks
  config.subscribe 'charge.failed', YourChargeFailed
end
```

What I can't figure out how to write the `YourChargeFailed` part. I've tried something like:

```
 config.subscribe 'order.payment_succeeded', ActiveRecord::Subscription.after_successful_payment
```

but I get `undefined method after_successful_payment for #<Class:0x007fb845849b30>`

How can I successfully subscribe to Stripe events, capture the return data, and initiate a callback function?

Thanks!

UPDATE

Here is what I've tried, and the corresponding errors I'm receiving:

purchases_helper.rb

```
module PurchasesHelper
  require 'stripe'

  def stripe_webhook(event)
    puts 'Purchases Helper'
    puts 'invoice.payment_succeeded'
    @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(event[:data][:object][:customer])

    @user = User.find_by(email: @customer[:email])

    @badge = Badge.find_by(condition: '2019Purchase')
    @badges_user = BadgesUser.find_by(user_id: @user.id, badge_id: @badge.id)
    # if @badges_user === nil
    #   BadgesUser.create(user_id: user.id, badge_id: badge.id)
    # end
    puts 'badge created'
  end
end
```

initializers/koudoku.rb

```
Koudoku.setup do |config|
  include ::PurchasesHelper

  config.subscribe 'charge.succeeded' do |event|
    puts 'charge created'
    ::PurchasesHelper.stripe_webhook(event)
  end

end
```

ERROR:

```
undefined method `stripe_webhook' for PurchasesHelper:Module excluded from capture: Not configured to send/capture in environment 'development'

NoMethodError (undefined method `stripe_webhook' for PurchasesHelper:Module):
```

Another attempt:

```
Koudoku.setup do |config|
  config.subscribe 'charge.succeeded' do |event|
    puts 'charge created'
    PurchasesHelper.stripe_webhook(event)
  end
end
```

ERROR:

```
undefined method `stripe_webhook' for PurchasesHelper:Module excluded from capture: Not configured to send/capture in environment 'development'

NoMethodError (undefined method `stripe_webhook' for PurchasesHelper:Module):
```

3rd Attempt:

```
Koudoku.setup do |config|
  include PurchasesHelper

  config.subscribe 'charge.succeeded' do |event|
    puts 'charge created'
    stripe_webhook(event)
  end

end
```

ERROR:

```
A copy of PurchasesHelper has been removed from the module tree but is still active! excluded from capture: Not configured to send/capture in environment 'development'

ArgumentError (A copy of PurchasesHelper has been removed from the module tree but is still active!):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see only one problem with your code.

```
module PurchasesHelper
  require 'stripe'

  def self.stripe_webhook(event) # NB self.
    puts 'Purchases Helper'
    puts 'invoice.payment_succeeded'
    @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(event[:data][:object][:customer])

    @user = User.find_by(email: @customer[:email])

    @badge = Badge.find_by(condition: '2019Purchase')
    @badges_user = BadgesUser.find_by(user_id: @user.id, badge_id: @badge.id)
    # if @badges_user === nil
    #   BadgesUser.create(user_id: user.id, badge_id: badge.id)
    # end
    puts 'badge created'
  end
end
```

and then you call it by saying

```
Koudoku.setup do |config|
  config.subscribe 'charge.succeeded' do |event|
    puts 'charge created'
    PurchasesHelper.stripe_webhook(event)
  end
end
```

This should work

Wait but Why?!

`Modules` are a way of grouping together methods, classes, and constants. `Modules` give you two major benefits.

1. provide a namespace and prevent name clashes
2. implement the mixin facility (when you `include` them)

You've defined an instance method on the `Module` that when included it will appear on every instance of the object.

but you are not doing that in this case. You want to call `stripe_webhook` on the `Module` itself.

adding `self. stripe_webhook` in this case = `PurchasesHelper. stripe_webhook` which is the way to define a methods on the class/module.

You can even do more freaky stuff like:

```
class Animal
  def self.all
    %w[dog cat bird]
  end
end

def Animal.include?(a)
  self.all.include?(a)
end

Animal.include?('cat') # true
Animal.include?('virus') # false
```

so you can even define methods on the Animal class outside the scope of the class and it will work.

To sum up:

in this example:

```
module PurchasesHelper
  def self.stripe_webhook(event)
    #...
  end
end
```

is equal to

```
module PurchasesHelper
  def PurchasesHelper.stripe_webhook(event)
    #...
  end
end
```

which is why just adding `self` allows you to call `PurchasesHelper.stripe_webhook`

Comment: Wow... so simple yet the only thing I didn't try! I accepted and gave you the bounty. Can you quickly explain why adding `self` solved the problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer to include why. Tell me if it is still not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

On Koudoku doc's, it says it actually uses stripe_event to handle that https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event

So, looking on the strip_event examples, you can pass a block and do whatever you need or pass something that respond to the `call` method https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event#usage

Comment: Yes - but how? Do I write a method in the model and call that? As I said above, I tried something like ` config.subscribe 'order.payment_succeeded', ActiveRecord::Subscription.after_successful_payment`. How would the last part work?

Comment: I don't know what does your method need to do, but there's an example on that link, it creates a class CustomerCreated, passes CustomerCreated.new to the subscribe and inside CustomerCreated it implements the `call` method, you put your code in there.